# Importing cx_Oracle in Jupyter note book gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: sql, database, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

i am using jupyter notebook and i am trying to do sql queries in jupyter book
but i got an error
[image]

Comment: `cx_Oracle` has a capital `O`.  Have you tried `import cx_Oracle` instead?

Answer (score 2):

To install **cx_Oracle** latest version 8.0.0 in your own laptop, you need the following components already installed:

- Python 3x
- An Oracle Instant Client version 11g or higher. Refer to download the instant client version to this link

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html

Steps to Download and Install cx_Oracle Package for Python on Windows. In my case, I like better the version available in GitHub

https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle

1.Click on the Download cx_Oracle link to download the package from Github. It will download a zip file into your laptop.

2.Extract the zip file to a folder on Windows. For example, C:\cx_oracle.

3.Now open the command prompt and change the current directory to the C:\cx_oracle directory to install cx_Oracle package.

4.Then run the following command.

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade pip
```

It will install the cx_Oracle package for Python on Windows, and you will get the messages as shown below.

```
Collecting pip
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 1.3MB 2.5MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

**Important** if you have more than one version of Python, use the one associated to Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the package first:

```
pip install cx-Oracle
```

Comment: you have a typo error. It is `cx_Oracle` , with underscore ;)

Comment: You are right, it was not a typo. It actually exists, but it is a link to the real one. Good to know .

Answer (score 0):

In simple words for anaconda users
while installing the package use small case letters [source](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cx_oracle)

```
conda install -c conda-forge cx_oracle
```

now while importing the package use init cap as

```
import cx_Oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebook comes as part of Anaconda Distribution. So, use conda install cx_Oracle in Jupyter cell. It will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35115449)

Comment: I happen to use pip not conda with Juptyer notebooks. It's a user choice. Another note: cx_Oracle was replaced by python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).